# Unjustified Text in Caption

Tags: captions

I use the code:

```
\documentclass[pra,12pt,reprint,superscriptaddress,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}
{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}
{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{(Color online) (a) $\Gamma(\tau)$ versus $\tau$ for $J=1$. The blue      dashed curve shows the decay rate if the initial state is repeatedly measured; the red curve shows the decay rate if the optimal projective measurement is repeatedly made. We have used $G = 0.01, \omega_c = 50, \beta = 1$; }
\end{figure}

\twocolumngrid

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

The text is unjustified. When I revert back to the standard `article` document class, I get the expected output: figures with justified captions.

What could be going on with this environment?

Comment: in some code you have not shown (possibly caption package setup) centred caption alignmnet has been specified. it is always best to post a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do I rectify the error?

Comment: you have given no hint that allows anyone to help, somewhere you have specified centering, you have to just not specify that (the default is justified text) but if you do not show what you did it is hard to say what part of your code is wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I checked my code. It seems I haven't specified centering anywhere; a quick search on the TeX file yields no result for center, centering etc. This is the only figure I have added in the file as well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Even when I use `\usepackage[justification=justified]{caption}` in the preamble, I get the same result.

Comment: sorry it is impossible to debug code that is not shown. make a small one page, one figure, document that shows the problem, use `\includegraphics{example-image}` as the image, so that anyone can run it and debug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The issue is that the minimal example I create on a different file works just fine; I don't know what's the issue. Even when I explicitly tell TeX to justify the caption, it isn't doing so.

Comment: Exactly. The problem is in some part of your document. the way to make a minimal example is not to start from scratch, start from a copy of your document and delete everything you can while still showing the error. when you can delete no more, post the result.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Check the edit!

Comment: Right.  If you compile it says `Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
`  Seems like good advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the caption package says that it is not compatible with the OPs document class.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}
            {\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}
            {\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{(Color online) (a) $\Gamma(\tau)$ versus $\tau$ for $J=1$. The blue      dashed curve shows the decay rate if the initial state is repeatedly measured; the red curve shows the decay rate if the optimal projective measurement is repeatedly made. We have used $G = 0.01, \omega_c = 50, \beta = 1$; }
    \end{figure}

    \twocolumngrid

\end{document}
```

**Don't use `caption`; it specifically provides a warning not to use it.**

Comment: ...or use `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` as an alternative.